# Disable wishlist button for the product once added into wishlist

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community

Suppose there is a product A. Once we add the product into wishlist, it should not allow us to add the same product A once again. The wishlist icon for the product should be disabled.

For our current website, if I add the same product again it increases the quantity of the product.

please help us with some solution.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file

> frontend\your_package\your_theme\template\catalog\product\view\addto.phtml

and replace the following code

```
<?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $_wishlistSubmitUrl ?>" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submitLight(this, this.href); return false;" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

with this code

```
<?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
<?php
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    $wishList = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customer);
    $wishListItemCollection = $wishList->getItemCollection();
    if (count($wishListItemCollection)) {
        $arrProductIds = array();
        foreach ($wishListItemCollection as $item) {
            $arrProductIds[] = $item->getProductId();
        }
    }
    if(in_array($_product->getId(), $arrProductIds)){
?>      
    <li><span class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></span></li>
<?php   
    }else{ 
?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $_wishlistSubmitUrl ?>" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submitLight(this, this.href); return false;" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
<?php   
    }
?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This will disable the "Add to Wishlist" button on **catalog_product_view** page. You can use the same coding practice anywhere you want to disable the wishlist button.

Comment: Salid Thanks for the help. It worked fine for us on product page. But we need the same functionality on category page and Quick view:

Comment: <a href="<?php if(Mage::getStoreConfig("ajaxcart/addtolinks/enablecategory", $code)):?>javascript:void(0)<?php else: ?><?php echo$this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?><?php endif; ?>" <?php if(Mage::getStoreConfig("ajaxcart/addtolinks/enablecategory", $code)):?>onclick="ajaxWishlist(this,'<?php echo$this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>','<?php echo $_product->getId()?>');"<?php endif;?> class="addtowishlist" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?>"><i class="icon-wishlist"></i></a><?php endif; ?> Can u pls help to provide same thing with this code?

Comment: Hey can u help me how to edit the above code?

Answer (score 0):

To disable wishlist link for all products which has been already added in wishlist you have to first find all the product in wishlist then you have to compare their product id with current product id. If it matches then you can disable the link. You can find the wishlist button in this file.

/app/design/frontend/your_theme_name/default/template/ajax/catalog/product/view/addto.phtml

Code to find product id of current product

In addto.phtml file there is an object of product. You can find the product id in following way

```
$currentProductId = $_product->getId()
```

Code to find product in wishlist

```
$flag = FALSE;
     $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
  if($customer->getId())
{
      $wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customer, true);
        $wishListItemCollection = $wishlist->getItemCollection();
 foreach ($wishListItemCollection as $item)
 {
       $wishlistProductId = $item->getProductId();
    if($currentProductId == $wishlistProductId) {
        $flag = TRUE;break; 
    }
}
}
```

Code to disable the wishlist link

```
 if($flag) {

    <li><a href="#" style="pointer-events: none;" onclick="wishlistForm.submitAjaxWishlist(this, '<?php echo $_wishlistSubmitUrl ?>', '<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>');
            return false;" class="drvy_link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>

} else {

<li><a href="#" onclick="wishlistForm.submitAjaxWishlist(this, '<?php echo $_wishlistSubmitUrl ?>', '<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>');
            return false;" class="drvy_link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>

}
```

Here style="pointer-events: none;" will disable the link.